# How to remove an item from a ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I am looking for a way to remove a ListView item from outside of ListView.builder.
Item name and index are known. I was hopping to achieve this via **ListView.removeAt(itemIndex);** but unfortunately this does not work.

In general... there are two FloatingActionButtons: fab1 and fab2. Once fab2 is pressed removeItem(itemName) function is called in order to remove data from database (this works OK) and once data is removed item should be removed from ListView (this does not work since I do not know how to refer to ListView).

Could you please advise on how to remove an item from a ListView in this case?

The full code is attached bellow:

```
  Future<List<PostListDetails>> postsFuture = getPosts();
  bool showButton = false;
  String itemName ="";
  int itemIndex = 0;


  static Future<List<PostListDetails>> getPosts() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = await prefs.getString('token');
    final listID = await prefs.getString('listID');
    final lista = await prefs.getString('lista');

    Response response = await post(Uri.parse('someURL'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
      body: <String, String>{
                  'listID': '$listID',
      },
    );

    if(response.statusCode != 200){
      print('Błąd połączenia z bazą danych...  status[${response.statusCode}]');
    }

    final List body = json.decode(response.body);
    return body.map((e) => PostListDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }


void removeItem(String nazwa) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = await prefs.getString('token');
    final listID = await prefs.getString('listID');

    try{
      Response response = await post(Uri.parse('SomeURL'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
        body: <String, String>{
          'listID': '$listID',
          'nazwa': nazwa,
        },
      );

      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        //ListView.removeAt(itemIndex);  <--- I do not know how to do this
        
      }else{
        print('Błąd połączenia z bazą danych...  status[${response.statusCode}]');
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
            heroTag: "fab1",
            onPressed: () {
              print('---> addList()');
              // addList();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
            label: const Text('Dodaj'),
          ),
          if (showButton)
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: "fab2",
              onPressed: () {
                print('---> removing $itemName');
                removeItem(itemName);  // this function removes data from database
                setState(() => showButton = false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              label: const Text('Usuń'),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Lista zakupowa'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("Brak danych...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        int customCompare(PostListDetails a, PostListDetails b) {
          if (a.status != b.status) {
            return a.status!.toInt() - b.status!.toInt();
          }
          final int categoryCompare = a.kategoria.toString().compareTo(b.kategoria.toString());
          if (categoryCompare != 0) {
            return categoryCompare;
          }
          return a.nazwa.toString().compareTo(b.nazwa.toString());
        }
        return GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            itemName = post.nazwa!;
            itemIndex = index;
            setState(() => showButton = true);
          },
          child: Container(
            color: post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5, horizontal: 0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
            height: 50,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        post.nazwa!,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${post.waga!.toString()} g.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 0,
                        child: Row(),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 10,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            CatIcon(imagePath: (Cat2Ico(post.kategoria!.toString()))),
                            Checkbox(
                              value: Int2Bool(post.status!.toInt()),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  post.status = Bool2Int(value!);
                                });
                                saveStatus(post.nazwa!, post.status!, index);
                                posts.sort(customCompare);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

---

UPDATE 1
I have updated the source code and moved ListView.remove... into removeItem function.

---

UPDATE 2

Bellow final code after the changes:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
            heroTag: "fab1",
            onPressed: () {
              print('---> addList()');
              // addList();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
            label: const Text('Dodaj'),
          ),
          if (showButton)
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: "fab2",
              onPressed: () {
                removeItem(itemName).then((value){
                  setState((){
                    itemToRemove = true;
                  });
                });
                setState(() => showButton = false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              label: const Text('Usuń'),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Lista zakupowa'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("Brak danych...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
    if (itemToRemove) {
      posts.removeWhere((element) => element.nazwa == itemName);
      itemToRemove=false;
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        int customCompare(PostListDetails a, PostListDetails b) {
          if (a.status != b.status) {
            return a.status!.toInt() - b.status!.toInt();
          }
          final int categoryCompare = a.kategoria.toString().compareTo(b.kategoria.toString());
          if (categoryCompare != 0) {
            return categoryCompare;
          }
          return a.nazwa.toString().compareTo(b.nazwa.toString());
        }
        return GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            itemName = post.nazwa!;
            itemIndex = index;
            setState(() => showButton = true);
          },
          child: Container(
            color: post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5, horizontal: 0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
            height: 50,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        post.nazwa!,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${post.waga!.toString()} g.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 0,
                        child: Row(),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 10,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            CatIcon(imagePath: (Cat2Ico(post.kategoria!.toString()))),
                            Checkbox(
                              value: Int2Bool(post.status!.toInt()),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  post.status = Bool2Int(value!);
                                });
                                saveStatus(post.nazwa!, post.status!, index);
                                posts.sort(customCompare);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I see that based on your code, the widget is stateful. So when you remove an item in your list of items, you need to cause the widget itself to redraw by changing the state. Since you did not add the code that defines your stateful widget, it is kind of hard to understand what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: make sure you have the right index, print, or debug it to understand,
and write your remove method in another section

Comment: OK... I have updated post with more code example for better understating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved in many ways.

1. Wait until the item is successfully deleted from the database then updated the app. This will use loaders to await the database transaction and setState to update the UI once completed.
2. By getting the index of the list item and deleting it by updating the state of the app. `posts.removeAt(itemIndex);`

I would suggest you use way 1. Because you'll be able to tell if something in the DB went wrong simply by using `Future` and `.then()`

Do this

```
void removeItem(String nazwa) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = await prefs.getString('token');
    final listID = await prefs.getString('listID');

    try{
      Response response = await post(Uri.parse('SomeURL'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
        body: <String, String>{
          'listID': '$listID',
          'nazwa': nazwa,
        },
      );

      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        //ListView.removeAt(itemIndex); Don't need this
       // just refresh UI here
       setState(() { });//<==remove this if you do not want to refresh the entire screen
        
      }else{
        print('Błąd połączenia z bazą danych...  status[${response.statusCode}]');
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Then for the UI to update based on the change of DB

```
Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
           future: postsFuture,//Replace with getPosts() to directly/actively read from DB 
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("Brak danych...");
            }
          },
        ),
```

For you to show change in progress use `CircularProgressIndicator()` like this

```
...
bool isLoading = false;
...
FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: "fab2",
              onPressed: () {
                print('---> removing $itemName');
                //loading
                setState((){
                    isLoading = true;
                  });
                removeItem(itemName).then((value){
                     setState((){
posts.removeWhere((element) => element.itemName == itemName);//<==please confirm that element.itemName is in your model class else correct it
                    isLoading = false;
                  });};  // this function removes data from database
                setState(() => showButton = false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              label: const Text('Usuń'),
            ),
```

use this in you body like this

```
 body: isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("Brak danych...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: OK... I have added more code and moved removeAt into removeItem function. Could you please look at this and advise...?

Comment: Wow... lots of changes... Thank you for your effort :). I thought I would be a matter of one line of code... I have applied all the changes and it works, but there is one issue with this. The whole list is updated, not a single row. Can you imagine what will happen on slow internet connection? Is there a way to remove or update just UI - one ListView item (one row) instead of all items (rows) to improve this?

Comment: Yes thats possible. Let me make the few changes

Comment: If this solved your issues, mark as correct

Comment: Thank you :) - I have already accepted your answer.

Comment: I have an issue with posts.removeWhere((element) => element.itemName == itemName); - got an error "posts undefined name"... any hints please...

Comment: I said in the comment that you need to change the name to yours that is in the model class or the name in the API

Comment: I understand that element.itemName should be changed to element.nazwa in my case ( as defined in API) but I have no clue how to change "posts." I did try PostListDetails but this will not work... "posts" is defined in Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) not in Widget build(BuildContext context)

Comment: OK... I have sorted this out somehow... Now it removes one item (row) nicely without blinking... I will update the code later today... anyway... you helped me a lot. THANK YOU for this :)